# Rotate an image around a specific point

Tags: rotation, rmagick

Is it possible to rotate an image around a specific point, rather than the center? I see options for RVG's, but not for Magick::Image's :/

http://www.simplesystems.org/RMagick/doc/rvgxform.html#rotate <- RVG pivot point

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angle -= angleSpeed * delta;
image.x = target.x + sin(angle) * distanceFromTarget;
image.y = target.y + cos(angle) * distanceFromTarget;
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try changing the anchor point of the image to where you want it to rotate around, instead of the center

Comment: I can't seem to find any anchor point methods for images in the documentation, what would it be under?